# AspectJ with Spring AOP combined

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I am looking to work out an application that supports full AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. I have 2 classes in which one point cut is on a method so the Spring AOP works fine but the other classes needs a point cut on a field for which I would need AspectJ. Could somebody please help me with this.

Class in which I would need AspectJ for **get** expression in pointcut. The issue is that the class that I am looking to get compiled by AspectJ had some dependencies to be injected. How will those work? How to satisfy those dependencies. Am I missing and config regarding the aspectJ

**LocalizationAspect.Java**

```
    @Aspect
    @Configurable
    public class LocalizationAspect {

        private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LocalizationAspect.class);

        @Autowired
        private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
        private HashOperations<String, String, Object> hashOps;

        @Autowired
        private CacheKeys cacheKeys;
        @Autowired
        private LocalizedTextLookupService localizedTextLookupService;

        @Value("${product}")
        private String product;


        @Pointcut("get(@com.util.Localized java.lang.String com..*.*) || get(@com.util.Localized java.lang.String com..*.*)")
        public void isLocalized() {}

        @Around("isLocalized()")
        public String getLocalized(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
            String originalValue = (String) pjp.proceed();
**//Do some operation with the original value and change it**

            return value;
        }

    }
```

This class should be should compiled by AspectJ.

Other class that uses Spring AOP but has to use it on a method so spring AOP would work fine.

```
    @Aspect
    @Configurable
    @Component
    public class ScoresExecutorAspect {

        private Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(ScoresExecutorAspect.class);

        @Autowired
        private ScoresExecutorLogService scoresExecutorLogService;

        @Value("${EnableScoringLog}")
        private boolean isLoggingEnabled;

        @Pointcut("execution(@com.util.ScoresExecutor * com..*.*(..)) && @annotation(scoresExecutor) && args(.., eLogger)")
        public void isScoresExecutor(ScoresExecutor scoresExecutor, ScoresExecutorLogger eLogger) {}

        @Around("isScoresExecutor(scoresExecutor, eLogger)")
        public Object logScoreExecution(ProceedingJoinPoint jointPoint, ScoresExecutor 
 scoresExecutor, ScoresExecutorLogger eLogger) throws Throwable {
             // Do some code here 
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <beans default-lazy-init="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
           xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
           xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
           xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"      
           xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
           xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
           xmlns:solr="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd         
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.        
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd         
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd         
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd   
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/task  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd 
           http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr/spring-solr-1.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


        <aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true"></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
         <task:annotation-driven executor="executorWithPoolSize" mode="aspectj" />
         <task:executor id="executorWithPoolSize" pool-size="5-125" queue-capacity="6000"/>
           <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaDialect">
                <bean class="com.connection.CustomJpaDialect" />
            </property>
        </bean>

         <bean id="loggingAspect" class="com.util.LocalizationAspect" 
         factory-method="aspectOf" />

        <beans xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">
            <cache:annotation-driven/>
        </beans>
        <beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xsi:schemaLocation="         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
            <mvc:annotation-driven>
                <mvc:argument-resolvers>
                    <bean
                        class="com..controller.ShlUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
                </mvc:argument-resolvers>
            </mvc:annotation-driven>
        </beans> 
    </beans>
```

**Localized.java**

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Localized {

    String lookupName() default "";
}
```

**MainElement.Java**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "main_elements", schema = "dbo")
    @Configurable(preConstruction = true, autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
    public class MainElements implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainElements.class);
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;

        @Localized
        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;
        // getters and setters
        }
```

**ScoresExecutor.java**

```
 @Target({ElementType.METHOD})
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @Inherited
 @Documented
 public @interface ScoresExecutor {
    ExecutorWorkflow workflow() default ExecutorWorkflow.OTHER;
    boolean persist() default false;
 }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.shl.tc</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin</artifactId>
    <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>
    <version>${GIT_BRANCH}${packaging.version}</version>
    <name>admin</name>
    <properties>
        <package.version>21.0.0</package.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.7</aspectj.version>
        <GIT_BRANCH></GIT_BRANCH>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <roo.version>1.2.5.RELEASE</roo.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <ehcache.version>2.6.2</ehcache.version>
        <wro4j.version>1.7.3</wro4j.version>
        <buildNumber>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildNumber>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <apachetiles.version>3.0.5</apachetiles.version>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>speech-to-text</artifactId>
                <version>6.7.0</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
                <version>6.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
               <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
               <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>


        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
             <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${roo.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.roo.addon.json</artifactId>
            <version>${roo.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-js-resources</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
           <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
           <version>${apachetiles.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ceb.roo.widget</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ceb.roo.widget</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

</dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
                    <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>

                <dependencies>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                 <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions> 
                <configuration>

                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>true</weaveWithAspectsInMainSourceFolder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                      <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
                  <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>      
                  <fork>true</fork>
                  <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin</executable>                
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                            <arguments>
                                <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                            </arguments>
                        </buildCommand>
                        <buildCommand>
                            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                        </buildCommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I am missing a clear explanation about what is not working as expected. Looking at your POM, it seems as if you use the AspectJ compiler globally, i.e. it will compile both aspects, not just the one you think should be compiled. Or is the Spring AOP aspect in another module? Another question is why you use compile-time weaving (CTW) instead of load-time weaving (LTW) as recommended by the Spring manual. Please explain your reasons. As for LTW, I never managed to get both Spring AOP and AspectJ to work at the same time, either 100% Spring AOP or 100% AspectJ. Was that your problem?

Comment: You also declare `LocalizationAspect` as a bean - strangely named `loggingAspect`, by the way - as if you want it to be used as a Spring AOP aspect even though you wrote you only want it used as an AspectJ aspect. Many questions, sorry. Could you maybe also make it a bit easier to reproduce your situation by pushing your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to GitHub, so I can clone the repository and run your application?